# Is there such a switch?

Tags: 12v, toggle-switch

I am looking for a single 12V DC switch which has an on-off-on actuator that will do the following: two 12 volt+ input pins completely separate from each other, each with its own two loads. In other words, when switch is in up position, only ONE power source in with two loads going out. The same would be true for the down position. The two power sources should never share the load together. I am wanting to run two 12V devices from one switch using two separate power sources. I hope this makes sense! :-) Smiles

Comment: btw, one is ACC only (vehicle switch on or running) and the other is by straight 12V battery only with vehicle off.

Comment: Sounds like it could be done with an on-off-on DPDT switch. What type of switch and what amp rating. 12VDC not a big deal for most but the amp rating will matter.

Comment: Adding a schematic of how you want this switch to operate may be helpful in clarifying what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You want a SPDT (single pole, double throw) switch with break-before-make. Your description is a little confusing, because you first said you want on-off-on which is a three position switch...I'm assuming you really just want two positions.

The two "throws" connect to your 12V power sources and the single "pole" connects to your loads.

Comment: I was thinking DPDT as the OP mentions 2 inputs each with 2 outputs? Maybe I am reading it wrong?

Comment: @Robert they share the power supply so they just run two wires from the spdt.

Comment: @Passerby I was confused with the "I am wanting to run two 12V devices from one switch using two separate power sources."

Comment: @Robert his comment mentions ACC and Battery. So it's an auto wiring setup. The sources are only different due to a key switch.

Answer (score 0):

A SPDT would do what you want. A DPDT would work the same, just connect the same power source to the same pole on the other side. ***A On-Off-On spdt switch would be best, allowing you to turn it off completely if needed. Wiring stays the same.***

The switch is literally connecting the center terminal to the other two pins, depending on which side is connected. We take advantage of that by connecting the two sources to the outer throws and the load to the center terminal.

[image]

Two ways to wire it. One is if your existing circuits and fuse are enough to handle the two new devices, and the switch can handle the current (Most automotive switches at a auto store can do 10 Amps). The second has you adding a new circuit or wire from the battery, fuse, and relay. The SPST (or a SPDT or DPDT relay ignoring the other pins) is switched on by your switch and power source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foVsKI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Of course you know that running this off the battery when the car or source is off, you can drain it.**

Comment: I have already tried a dpdt switch, both rocker and toggle. They have six terminals, four loads out and two power sources in. If I connect the ACC to one of the power ins and the straight battery to the other, that means that BOTH will be working at the same time when the switch is flipped up or down which I do not want. I need to use one switch to separately switch between two things: power two 12V devices using ACC only when the vehicle is running, OR power the same two devices straight from the batter when the vehicle is off....switch up - ACC only, when switch down, straight battery only.

Comment: The upper diagram looks interesting, but does it require two switches? One for ACC and one for straight battery connected to the same two loads? Thanks for your help. :-)

Comment: The wiring, fuses, and switches that I will use should easily handle the loads.

Comment: And, if I may ask another question due to my ignorance, if ACC pos wires and a pos wire straight from the 12V battery are touching or connected together, would that matter or give you some sort of feedback or short? Thanks :-)

Comment: I guess this is confusing....I just need some sort of 12V DC switch with one power in (ACC) going out to two loads, and another separate power in (straight from the battery) going out to the same two loads...both being totally separate from each other on the same one switch so I can have ACC only or straight from battery only and the two power sources are never on at the same time.

Comment: And yes.....thanks for the advice...I understand that when the switch is straight from the battery, it could run the battery down if the devices are left on.

Comment: @David, the upper one only has one switch SW1 that you add, the other switch is your ignition key switch, which turns on the acc/on circuits. Yes, connecting acc and always on/battery wires directly together would cause a feedback since we don't add any diodes. **What you are missing is that by connecting the switch as I describe, you get exactly what you want.** The DPDT switch you have doesn't have 4 loads out, 2 power in. It doesn't know how you connect them. It's just a metal connection. So by putting power on the outer terminal, and the load on the middle terminal, you get what you want.